# Why are unit tests regarded "cheap" during development?

Tags: unit-testing

I am finally getting my feet wet with testing. Currently I am trying to understand the differences between different approaches and techniques.

One thing that always strikes me is the notion that unit tests are often regarded as cheap way for developers (and only developers) to test their code, compared to maybe BDD style testing.

If I got that right, unit tests cover a single function or method each, testing it as isolated as possible to ensure the internals are wired up correctly, whereas BDD tests are validating that the correct thing is happening. In a TL;DR version maybe like this: "When I click this button, did the event handler get called?" vs "When I click this button, did the product has been put into the shopping cart?".

Now, why are unit tests considered cheaper then other ways of testing?

To my eye, unit tests can even be a lot more daunting because it's not enough to validate that the right thing happened (*what*), but with unit tests you have to actually validate *how* this happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit tests are cheap in a few senses:

1. Reasoning twice about the same problem.

First, the reasoning for the unit test: GIVEN some well-understood input and expected output, WHEN the code under test runs, THEN some set of assertions should hold true.

Next the reasoning for the code under development: input, transformation, and output.

When you are writing the test code and the code under development without breaking your concentration, you get the code and repeatable tests without the overhead of reintroducing yourself or another person to the problem. And the reasoning from the test perspective better informs you for writing the code under test.

So, it is cheap, because you don't require much additional reasoning, and that reasoning complements the reasoning to write the code under test.

2. Unit tests have fewer dependencies.

Ideally, they only depend on one module. (I am not an idealist. If you need more than one module to get the job done, then so be it.) This makes unit test run much faster. Unit tests are less likely to change because of a change in a module besides the one under test.

So, it is cheap because you have little setup to run the tests, and they take little time to execute.

3. Unit test give developers very quick feedback

The problem with the waterfall model is that it does not take into account feedback. Agile is designed not to prevent feedback loops -- it considers them inevitable. There is no quicker feedback than a test that runs in seconds, and is available as soon as you write your code.

So, it is cheap because you have little time investment before you get feedback on the correctness of the code.

4. Unit tests reduce the risks of refactoring

Back in the late '90s, everyone was afraid of changing their code, because they couldn't be sure of the side effects of changes, and a change required a large test effort. With the quick feedback of unit tests, developers can refactor with far less fear of unintended side effects and impacts to broader systems.

So it is cheap because you can be more confident in small code adjustments, and many small code adjustments can amount to much better code.

5. Automated unit tests facilitate continuous integration

Automated unit tests give immediate feedback for the developer. Continuous integration is an approach including the automated execution of unit tests and other automated tests. This provides feedback on the entire project for the entire team. It also increases the confidence in the builds, because they are isolated from a particular developer's workstation.

So it is cheap because it facilitates some level of "full" testing after every code change, which is better than waiting a long time for lots of manual testing. Much cheaper than the army of testers to accomplish the same.

Moreover, you say that unit tests examine the "how" and not the "what". Unit tests should concentrate on the "what." Unit tests should test the public interface of a class or module. Some unit tests leverage mocks to reduce the number of dependencies. In Percival's book "Test-Driven Development With Python," he explains how using mocks ties the test closer to the implementation than the interface. There are tradeoffs between de-coupling from the implementation (no mocks, but maybe you need additional modules) and isolating from other modules (using mocks to isolate from other modules, possibly tying the test more to the implementation). There are lots of other tradeoff decisions along the way, and making the right decisions is not trivial.

Moreover, Percival espouses double-loop TDD or writing functional tests, followed by unit tests, followed by code under test. Behavior-driven development (BDD), as I understand it, leverages acceptance tests written in some domain specific code. I interpret these as more abstracted tests than the functional tests that Percival espouses. I don't make any argument that these BDD tests are too heavyweight. Frankly I don't have any relevant experience.

What I would encourage is that you have tests at multiple level of the test pyramid. If a particular test is well-suited to its purpose, and fits between levels, you don't have to unit-ize it or behavior-ize it. Just let it best fulfill its purpose.

It has been said about metrics, and it applies to automated unit test as well: automated testing is hard, and doing automated testing wrong can create maintenance headaches or a false sense of security. Still we have to do testing.

Answer (score 3):

Unit tests are "cheaper" in the sense that the resources required to perform them are less than that of other methods of testing. Unit tests are easy to do and allow for a function to be abstractly evaluated for correct functionality - they are NOT evaluated for how they will interact with the system as a whole.

Due to this, unit testing does NOT:

- Test system flow or component integration
- Require environmental knowledge/requirements

Due to the nature of unit testing, increases in productivity are gained, since less time is wasted performing integration or understanding system flow.

Good unit testing requires the following:

- Small and fast
- Easily executed, (provide quick turnaround)
- Fully automative
- Easy to interpret (pass or fail?)
- Simple to execute
- One command/program execution for full test suite
- No further input from the user required after execution

These specifications lead to testing that is fast, gets the job done, and has no need for human interaction, continuing even after faults are detected. For these reasons, unit testing "costs" less than other types of testing.